# Merge two duplicate rows with imputing values from each other

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe (df1) with only one column (col1) having identical values while other columns have missing values, for example as follows:

```
df1
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   col1     col2            col3       col4       col5       col6
--------------------------------------------------------------------
0| 1234     NaT             120        NaN        115        XYZ
1| 1234     2015/01/12      120        Abc        115        NaN
2| 1234     2015/01/12      NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

I would like to merge the three rows with identical col1 values into one row such that the missing values are replaced with values from the other rows where the values exist in place of missing values. The resulting df will look like this:

```
 result_df
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   col1     col2            col3       col4       col5       col6
--------------------------------------------------------------------
0| 1234     2015/01/12      120        Abc        115        XYZ
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove duplicates in columns names `col3` and `col4`:

```
s = df.columns.to_series()
df.columns = (s + '.' + s.groupby(s).cumcount().replace({0:''}).astype(str)).str.strip('.')
print (df)
   col1       col2   col3 col4  col3.1 col4.1
0  1234        NaT  120.0  NaN   115.0    XYZ
1  1234 2015-01-12  120.0  Abc   115.0    NaN
2  1234 2015-01-12    NaN  NaN     NaN    NaN
```

And then aggregate [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df = df.groupby('col1', as_index=False).first()
print (df)
   col1       col2   col3 col4  col3.1 col4.1
0  1234 2015-01-12  120.0  Abc   115.0    XYZ
```

Comment: @jezarel: your earlier codeline helped in getting the desired result, i.e. 
df = df.groupby('col1', as_index=False).first()

Comment: Sure, if columns names are unique, use `df = df.groupby('col1', as_index=False).first() ` only.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't change the columns names to be unique. I have now edited the columns name to be unique. Thanks a lot!